# output always gives last line or all lines

Tags: python, csv

I have two tab-delimited files, and I need to test every row in the first file against all the rows in the other file. For instance,

file1:

```
row1    c1    36    345   A
row2    c3    36    9949  B
row3    c4    36    858   C
```

file2:

```
row1    c1    3455  3800
row2    c3    6784  7843
row3    c3    10564 99302
row4    c5    1405  1563
```

let's say I would like to output all the rows in (file1) for which col[3] of file1 is smaller than any (not every) col[2] of file2, given that col[1] are the same.

Expected output:

```
row1    c1    36    345   A
row2    c3    36    9949  B
```

Since I am working in Ubuntu, I would like the input command to look like this:
python code.py [file1] [file2] > [output]

I wrote the following code:

```
import sys

filename1 = sys.argv[1]
filename2 = sys.argv[2]

file1 = open(filename1, 'r')

done = False

for x in file1.readlines():
    col = x.strip().split()
    file2 = open(filename2, 'r')
    for y in file2.readlines():
        col2 = y.strip().split()
        if col[1] == col2[1] and col[3] < col2[2]:
            done = True
            break
        else: continue
print x
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
row2    c3    36    9949  B
```

Basically I always get only the last row for which the condition in the nested loop was true. I tried this instead:

```
    if done == True: print x
```

(with one indentation), but now it prints all the rows in file1, regardless of the conditions tested in the previous loop. (>_<)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to reset `done` variable after the first match and you don't need the variable in this case. To fix the code, just replace `done = True` with `print x` and use `int(col[3]) < int(col2[2])` to compare the columns as numbers (integers).